# Predict Weibull instant hazard

Tags: r, survival-analysis, weibull

I am trying to model baseline hazard using different survival models.
For example I can model the cumulative baseline hazard using Cox as follows:

```
library(survival)
df <- aml
cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, df)
cox.summary <- basehaz(cox, centered = TRUE)
plot(cox.summary)
```

However Cox is not ideal for this and I would like to model instant hazards rather than cumulative, so I am trying to use Weibull as follows:

```
weibull <- survreg(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data=df, dist="weibull")
```

However I cannot work out how to predict the instant hazard from this. For example if I try the following code I just get a constant value (38.18681) at each time point.

```
predict(weibull, newdata=data.frame(time=df$time))
```

Where am I going wrong here ? In case I wasn't clear my aim is to visualize the instantaneous hazard in a plot of hazard vs time.

Comment: Another approach is to use the `rms` package's `psm` and `Hazard` functions.

Comment: Hi Frank - I wasn't aware of the package (until recently I did my survival modelling in Stata), however I will check it out. Just for my general education I would still like to know how to do it using `survreg` also

Comment: Hi again Frank. Wow figured out how to do it with your package in about 5 mins. Thanks - great package. I like the Hazard command to generate an output function for me -perfect! Leaving it open for the survreg answer.